# error Command failed with signal "SIGKILL". Next 14 and aws Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, frontend, aws-amplify, next.js14

I have an issue when I try to  deploy my next js app to AWS amplify an Error occurred that
error Command failed with signal "SIGKILL".

Next js 14

```
2024-02-14T11:38:36.569Z [INFO]: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2024-02-14T11:38:36.569Z [INFO]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
                                 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
                                 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2024-02-14T11:38:36.670Z [INFO]: ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
2024-02-14T11:38:36.671Z [INFO]: - Environments: .env.production
                                 - Experiments (use at your own risk):
                                 · missingSuspenseWithCSRBailout
2024-02-14T11:38:36.749Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build ...
2024-02-14T11:41:17.953Z [WARNING]: error Command failed with signal "SIGKILL".
2024-02-14T11:41:18.040Z [INFO]: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2024-02-14T11:41:18.151Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-02-14T11:41:18.151Z [INFO]: Please read more about Amplify Hosting's support for SSR frameworks to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-ssr-framework-support.html. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
2024-02-14T11:41:18.152Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1
2024-02-14T11:41:18.152Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-02-14T11:41:18.152Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

I successfully built the code locally without any errors. However, when I deploy the same code on AWS Amplify through GitHub, I encounter the mentioned error.

here is my yaml file

```
 version: 1.0
        frontend:
          phases:
            preBuild:
              commands:
                - nvm use 18
                - yarn install
            build:
              commands:
                - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
                - yarn run build
          artifacts:
            baseDirectory: .next/
            files:
              - "**/*"
          cache:
            paths:
              - node_modules/**/*
```